# Advice on writing to a log file with python

Tags: python

I have some code that will need to write about 20 bytes of data every 10 seconds.
I'm on Windows 7 using python 2.7

You guys recommend any 'least strain to the os/hard drive' way to do this?

I was thinking about opening and closing the same file very 10 seconds:

```
f = open('log_file.txt', 'w')
f.write(information)
f.close()
```

Or should I keep it open and just `flush()` the data and not close it as often?

What about `sqllite`? Will it improve performance and be less intensive than the open and close file operations?
(Isn't it just a flat file database so == to text file anyways...?)

What about `mysql` (this uses a local server/process.. not sure the specifics on when/how it saves data to hdd) ?

I'm just worried about not frying my hard drive and improving the performance on this logging procedure. I will be receiving new log information about every 10 seconds, and this will be going on 24/7 24 hours a day.
Your advice?

ie: Think about programs like utorrent that require saving large amounts of data on a constant basis for long periods of time, (my log file is significantly less data that those being written in such "downloader type programs" like utorrent)

```
import random
import time


def get_data():
    letters = 'isn\'t the code obvious'
    data = ''
    for i in xrange(20):
        data += random.choice(letters)
    return data

while True:
    f = open('log_file.txt', 'w')
    f.write(get_data())
    f.close()
    time.sleep(10)
```

My CPU starts whining after about 15 seconds... (or is that my hdd? )

Answer (score 13):

As expected, python comes included with a great tool for this, have a look at the [logging](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) module

Comment: Skimmed through it... I still don't understand how this improves file writing calls...

Comment: Post some code that you have tried and the problems you are facing, and we'd be glad to assist you!

Comment: @MistahX logging is a perfect swiss armyknife for this purpose. It gives you complete control. You can create round-robin loggin, start a new file when the size is aver a threshold and so on. Everyting is in the docs. BTW the while loop above is not a good idea!

Comment: ok i'll read it more carefully.. but what's wrong with the while loop? are you referring to the infinite nature of it or something else? ie: I use while True loops all the time and use 'break' to get out of them when a condition is met, is that a "bad idea" ?

Answer (score 4):

Use the logging framework. This is exactly what it is designed to do.

Edit: Balls, beaten to it :).

Comment: know the feeling, happens to me all the time ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about "frying" your hard drive - 20 bytes every 10 seconds is a small fraction of the data written to the disk in the normal operation of the OS.